# Does a large number of small files in a directory affect peformance

Tags: windows, coldfusion, server

We have CF10 running on a windows 2003 server. One of our applications is a sort of file management system. Users upload files, we store the type, username, and date in a database, then rename the file to the id from the sql row and save the file in a folder on the server. The number of files has swelled to nearly 500,000. Would it be beneficial to store the files in subdirectories?

Comment: I have not checked on a decent machine recently, but Windows used to REALLY struggle on over about 1000 files in a given directory. It just took an age (relatively) to do a dir scan to find files. Why would you NOT put them in a hierarchical structure? I presume the data itself has a sense of categorisation to it?

Comment: You might look at a Storage Area Network if you are storing that many files.

Comment: I should add that there isn't any directory commands after the upload, except users get links like "https://domain/path/sqlid.pdf"

Comment: Seems more like a system admin issue than a coding issue.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg: simply accessing the file requires a directory scan for the file system to find it to load it.

Comment: @ScottStroz reading between the lines, I'm seeing it as a question as to whether recoding is necessary to reimplement the storage more optimally. But... yeah, could go either way.

Comment: @AdamCameron That answers my question pretty well. I wasn't sure if the system "ignored" every other file if you gave it a very specific link.